# python to javascript numpy ndarray operation confusion

Tags: javascript, python, numpy

I am trying to convert some python numpy code into javascript, and I am unsure of what the follow code is actually doing.

`self.W = np.random.rand(size, size)-0.5`

`self.W /= 0.9`

What does the `- 0.5` do in this case? Does this subtract 0.5 from every number in the multi-dimensional array. Just below that line, does the division happen on every element inside of self.W? To convert to javascript, would I just iterate over all of the elements and apply the operation to the element at that index?

Also, in the following snippet, what is actually happening?? I have no idea what is happening. I am use to bracket notation being an index, but this looks like a condition (like ternary?), but it also looks like it is generating a new matrix to do this.

`self.W[np.random.rand(size, size)>self.sparsity] = 0`

Thanks for any help.

[Original Python Code on GitHub](https://github.com/Devrim-Celik/simple_echo_state_network/blob/master/ESN.py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably just install an appropriate version of Python and `numpy` when attempting a conversion like this.

With a few simple lines of testing on the CLI, you'd be able to answer your own question:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.rand(1, 2)
array([[0.08239857, 0.15732393]])
>>> x = np.random.rand(1, 2)
>>> x
array([[0.08155715, 0.57869165]])
>>> x - .5
array([[-0.41844285,  0.07869165]])
```

So, yes - the `numpy.ndarray` type has a subtract operation defined on it that, when presented with a number as the second operand and an array as the first, subtracts that number from each element of the array.

With the division, similarly:

```
>>> x *= 10
>>> x
array([[0.81557146, 5.78691654]])
>>> x /= 10
>>> x
array([[0.08155715, 0.57869165]])
```

The difference is that `/` would return a new result array (in `x / 10`) whereas `/=` assigns the result to `x`, overwriting its values in `x /= 10`.

The last example is more complicated, but very typical of how the `numpy` library is implemented. Similar to the operations like `-` and `/=` being distributed, applying a comparison to an array distributes it and returns an array of boolean values, which can then be used as an 'index' to select exactly those value of an array for which the array of boolean values is `True`.

It then proceeds to set exactly those selected values to `0`, in the example you gave.

Asking how to code those operations in JavaScript is just asking SO to write your code for you - now that you understand what happens, you should try to implement the same logic in JavaScript. If you run into specific issues you don't understand, you can ask separate questions about those.